# CSS Advanced Layout

Tags: html, css

Is is possible to achieve the below effect (click link for image) using CSS? HTML cannot be changed.

[image]

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS-only masonry solution as described here: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/